# Copying BigQuery result to another table is not working?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have noticed one weird problem on BigQuery in last 2-3 days, earlier it was working fine.

I have a bigquery table in a dataset located in EU region. I am running a simple SELECT query on that table and it ran without any issue.
Now, I am trying to save that query result into another bigquery table in the same dataset, it is giving below error -

> To copy a table, the destination and source datasets must be in the
> same region. Copy an entire dataset to move data between regions.

Strange part is that, other alternatives are working fine, such as -

1. Copying the source table to new table is working fine.
2. When I set the destination table in the query setting and run the query then it is able to save the query result into that configured table.
3. I ran the query and access the temporary table where BigQuery actually stores the query result and then copy that temporary table to destination table, this is also working.

Not sure why only the save result option is not working, it was working before though.

Anyone has any idea if something has changed on GCP recently?

Comment: Hi @VikashPareek, Is the issue resolved or are you still facing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to `create or replace table 'abc.de.omg' AS SELECT ....`  to store the same result.

edit: another workaround is to set it up as a schedule query and run it as a backfill once.

On another note, anyone finding this can comment on the reported bug here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/233184546 (i'm not the original poster)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the issue tracker, will be watching this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to save query results as the BigQuery table as below, I manually gave the Dataset name and it worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have source and destination dataset in different region.

you can share source and destination dataset screenshots to check the region.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question that I am trying to save the query result to a table in the SAME dataset. So source and destination are in same region and that's why other alternative options are working fine.

Comment: Same problem for me. How did you do this part: "I ran the query and access the temporary table where BigQuery actually stores the query result and then copy that temporary table to destination table, this is also working."

Comment: @MichelK, you can go to your job history and open the job detail then you will get the temporary table location.

Comment: @VikashPareek this trick worked, thanks!! For anyone who hasn't done this before (as myself), this means:  Personal history --> Click on last job --> Click on 'Temporary Table' --> When temp table opens, 'Copy' into the new table

Answer (score 0):

Tried to reproduce issue

Error when i typed dataset name manually.

[image]

Successfull When I selected dataset from drop-down - *Strange*

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work for me either I manually type the dataset name or select it from the drop-down list.